# Selenium not able to find element by tag name "body" (only for IE)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<body style="padding: 10px 25px; margin:0; left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;position:absolute;font:14px 'robotoregular'; cursor:text; width: auto;">
<br _moz_editor_bogus_node="TRUE"/>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVA CODE

```
public TemplateOfNewLetter enterTextMessageToMessageField(String textMessage){

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
        //WebElement body = waitElementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("html>body"));
        WebElement body = waitElementToBeClickable(By.tagName("body"));
        body.click();
        body.sendKeys(textMessage);
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        return this;
    }
```

I tried to use the code above but the issue is still reproduced in explorer (for FF and Chrome tests passed)

Please advice how can I enter text to the text message field

Comment: Can you share more details, such as detailed exception with line number where the exception is thrown

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.tagName: body
Build info: version: '2.47.0', revision: '0e4837e94b1fad0db93e88cd972ed3e235a22892', time: '2015-07-29 15:58:41'
System info: host: 'Lenovo-PC', ip: '172.20.127.248', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: I used different wait such as clickable, presence, visible

Comment: and also without any wait the result was the same not found

Answer (score 0):

1. you didn't have frame to switch to.
2. you can't send text to body.

Try to look how to use selenium in this link:
http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-webdriver-tutorials

Comment: As I mentioned in my question for FF and Chrome it's work but for IE it does not!

Comment: I have tried to use different locator by xpath by cssSelector but it did not help

Comment: I think the problem is html source representation in IE driver, try to work in FF if you can, but still i didn't get it how you can switch to not existed frame or send text to body and not to input tag...

Comment: Frame only one so for switching I use (0) an other way By.tagName("iframe") and send text to text field finding By.tagName("body")
I need to test in explorer too it's general requirements ((